# How to compare 2 integers in terms of how many times 1st Integer is greater than second

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking to find a formula in excel by which I can calculate how many times 1st integer is greater than second.

For Example:

```
A = 5
B = 1
Ans: (A/B) i.e 5/1 = 5
A is 5 times bigger than B. Simple Enough!!
```

Problem occurs when one integer is negative,
Example:

```
A = 10
B = -5
```

How do I calculate in excel, how much time A is bigger or smaller than B.

Condition: Any Integer could be negative (A or B)

Thank You!!

What I tried:

```
A = 10
B = -5
C = A / B 
C = 10 / -5 
C = -2 which is incorrect :(**
```

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. I am just trying to compare One negative and one positive integer here, to find how many times one is greater than other.

Comment: What is the answer to your 2nd example? 3? Can the 1st integer be negative?

Comment: I was thinking 3. Yes

Comment: 1st integer can be negative as well and both can be negative as well.

Comment: What do you expect from A=-10, B=2? -5? Or A is 20 times smaller than B? From A=-10, B=-2 -> C=A is 5 times smaller than B?

Comment: Let me check. Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: A = -10
B = 2
Ans: A is 5 times smaller than B, But the A = -10 and B = -2 will have the same result.

Comment: If the answer to your 2nd sample would be 3 then why not 6 when A=-10, B=2? Right now, your examples all require different types of calculation. When A=-10 and B=-2 the answer indeed would be 5 if it were up to me.

Comment: Yes, the answer should be 6 for A=-10 and B =2. 5 was incorrect. I am assuming we cannot get this by done by simple division. How do I achieve this in excel is again a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

[image]

Formula in `A4`:

```
=(MAX(A1:A2)-MIN(A1:A2))/MIN(ABS(A1:A2))+(OR(MIN(A1:A2)>0,MAX(A1:A2)<0))
```

Comment: Not quite there yet, try: -5 and -10, your formula gets to 1, -10 and -5 also get to 1

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Now only thing left for Rajsha to do is `="A is " & (MAX(A1:B1)-MIN(A1:B1))/MIN(ABS(A1:B1))+(OR(MIN(A1:B1)>0,MAX(A1:B1)<0)) & " times " & IF(A1<B1,"smaller","bigger") & " than B"` to fit his setup

Answer (score 0):

Thank You@ JvdV and Notus_panda: This works perfectly!!

`=(MAX(B1:B2)-MIN(B1:B2))/MIN(ABS(B1:B2))+(OR(MIN(B1:B2)>0,MAX(B1:B2)<0))`

`="A is " & (MAX(B1:B2)-MIN(B1:B2))/MIN(ABS(B1:B2))+(OR(MIN(B1:B2)>0,MAX(B1:B2)<0)) & " times " & IF(B1<B2,"smaller","bigger") & " than B"`

[image]